# Print Stack Trace in Output Window

Tags: c#, debugging

C#, WinForms: Is there a way I can see which methods are calling a specific method? well I can put a break point and see the call stack, but this one is UI related and it is a DoubleClick event, so I thought it will be helpful if something similar to Debug.Writeline(....) can also print call stack on a method so I could write it at the beginning of my method and see ok this time it is cvalled from this method, this time from that method, etc...

Comment: Instead of printing debug messages, you could just put your cursor on the method name and press Shift+F12 (Edit.FindAllReferences)...

Comment: yes but it does not mean all of those methods are calling my method in that specific execution path.  Envirnoment.StrackTrace answer is correct.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the [Environment.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace.aspx) property.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is [System.Diagnostics.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx). You simply create a new instance at the point where you want to look at the stack.

Beware, though, that creating a stack trace is very expensive.